# Is the speed of objects in time, in Galilean Relativity, a constant and invariant speed relative to all reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, spacetime, time, speed

(This question is only about Galilean Relativity. Not Special or General relativity.)

**Question**: Is it true that every object in the universe, **according only to Galilean Relativity** is traveling in time at the same speed?

Say we have 3 objects: call them *A* and *B* inside a 3rd *C* object's reference frame.

That reference frame consists of 1 dimension of space and one dimension of time. Those 2 A and B objects now, are separated by some small distance X. Is it ok to assume that both A and B objects (according to Galilean Relativity) and from the C objects reference frame - will be moving in time, at the same exact speed, which is V=1s/s? (one second every second measured by C).

Is it true to say that the speed of A and B in time will be V=1s/s, even if A or B are moving or accelerating in space?

So basically in Galilean Relativity the speed in which objects move in time (or age) is a constant and invariant speed? Constant because its always 1s/s and there is no way to increase or decrease that speed - and invariant because that value doesn't depend on any other object's reference frame?

[image]

(Of course that's all not right according to Einstein's Relativity)

Comment: Why complicate it so much? The textbooks all say that time is absolute in Galilean Relativity. Everyone agrees on the time. What don't you understand about that?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make sure that I understand the concept correctly and that Im also using the correct terminology. So time in Galilean relativity is constant and invariant... Just like the speed of C in spacetime in Einstein's Relativity, correct? I wanted to start by understanding Galilean relativity first so that I can move on to Einstein's Relativity. I have another question for example, that has to do with the speed of light (in Galilean relativity), whether or not its infinite and how that affects the preservation of causality in that framework.

Comment: @Nuke avoid asking different questions in the same post, as it makes it harder to navigate through the site (and answerers might know the answer to one question, but not the other).

Comment: Ok! I will do that, noted!

Comment: @Nuke as for time being constant and invariant, not really. Time passes, after all. Galilean time and the speed of light occur differently in each theory. $c$ is just a parameter, while the behaviour of time is related to the geometrical structure of spacetime itself. It is more appropriate to say that Galilean time is universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The "different speeds through time" of Relativity are a consequence of the fact that, in Relativity, time is an observer-dependent quantity. In Galilean spacetime, time is absolute to all observers. In particular, this means it is even a bit weird to talk about the "speed through time", since you don't have different notions of proper time and coordinate time as you do in Relativity, but the interpretation that every observer travels through time with speed $1$ seems perfectly reasonable.

We can also see this as a limit from Special Relativity, in which one would have
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \stackrel{c\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1.$$
Notice this calculation employs the proper time of the observer in Special Relativity, which is only defined for timelike trajectories. Nevertheless, lightlike trajectories correspond to massless particles, which can't be described in the framework of non-relativistic Mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to say... Yes, universality of time is a basic postulate of Newtonian mechanics, one of the first axioms that you see when you start learning the theory.